# How can I get PHP code run detail line by line

Tags: php, code-coverage, xdebug, trace

i am test php code,and with xdebug
i can use it function trace,to know function run one by one,and i can get the function params and return.
and i can use xdebug code coverage,to find this php code file,which line has been hit.

but, now i want to find,the code run line one by one

like a for loop

```
index.php
<?php 
for ($x=0; $x<=3; $x++) {
  if $x / 2 == 0 {
     echo "even num is：$x <br>";
  } else {
     echo "odd num is：$x <br>";
  }
} 
?>

index.php -> line1    
index.php -> line2 (for loop)
index.php -> line3 (if judge)
index.php -> line4 (if output)
index.php -> line2 (rerun for loop)
etc
```

is xdebug has the ability？or other tool supprt this？

thank you

Comment: Yes, you can step line by line using Xdebug. Just use editor/IDE that supports Xdebug (PhpStorm/NetBeans/VSCode/etc). For example, for PhpStorm check these links: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: thank you, for vscode,can i get that?

Comment: Just google [VSCode PHP debug](https://www.google.com/search?q=VSCode+PHP+debug). Check these links: https://www.codewall.co.uk/debug-php-in-vscode-with-xdebug/, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug (actual extension for VSCode).